# Returning a true value instead of integer value in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a simple function below which takes 2 lists ( with the same size) and a variable which stores some result.

My intention was to compare the first list's head with the second one and increase the result by one, and return it.

But instead I get `true` / `false`.

```
myfunction( [], [], 0).
myfunction([H1|T1], [H2|T2], N) :- 
        H1 > H2 -> myfunction(T1, T2, N1 + 1); myfunction(T1, T2, N1), N is N1 .
```

Comment: In Prolog you don't have functions, you have predicates. And you run programs in Prolog by satisfying goals, that means the answer to your queries are always `true` or `false`.

Comment: But how can I do something similar it? I know the length function, it returns a integer value.

Comment: No, it doesn't. See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) the documentation from swi-prolog for `length/2`.

Comment: Yeah that's also true, but somehow we can still return some values from it right?

Comment: Variables might get instantiated (through unification) when goals are satisfied. For example, satisfying a goal like `length([1,2,3], N)` binds variable `N` to 3, but the goal itself can be only true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating Prolog like an imperative/procedural language, but it doesn't work that way. You should read through some Prolog tutorials and/or books.

In Prolog, you define a *predicate* which defines a relation. When you define a predicate with variables, you are saying that, *These variables are related in such and such a way if...*. If Prolog succeeds in verifying the relation is true, the predicate response with "true" or "yes". Otherwise, it responds with "false" or "no".

Here's a rework of what you're trying to do:

```
my_predicate([], [], 0).
```

This relation is the "base case" and says that *the count of cases where the corresponding values in the first list are greater than the second when the lists are empty is 0*.

```
my_predicate([H1|T1], [H2|T2], N) :-
    my_predicate(T1, T2, N1),
    (  H1 > H2
    -> N is N1 + 1
    ;  N = N1
    ).
```

This relation says that *N is the count of cases where the corresponding values in the first list are greater than the second **if** N1 is the count of cases for the tails, and N is N1 + 1 if the current head is greater, otherwise N is N1*.

If you want to make it tail recursive for efficiency, you can use an accumulator:

```
my_predicate(L1, L2, N) :-
    my_predicate(L1, L2, 0, N).

my_predicate([], [], N, N).
my_predicate([H1|T1], [H2|T2], A, N) :-
    (  H1 > H2
    -> A1 is A + 1
    ;  A1 = A
    ),
    my_predicate(T1, T2, A1, N).
```

Note that the above definition of `my_predicate/3` assumes you want failure if the lists are different length. If you don't want failure in those cases, you would need to redefine the base case(s).

Comment: Thanks. I always have difficulties when I change from one paradigm to other.

Comment: @BlediBoss in Prolog it's best to forget almost everything you know about how to program in other languages and study it "fresh". :) Too many people try to write Prolog programs using the same thinking they would in C++, Java, or any other imperative language.